# How to add an environment variable to AWS Lambda without removing what's there?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there a way to add a new environment variable to an AWS Lambda function without removing the ones already there?

(With the command line tools, that is.)

Answer (score 4):

I successfully used this as a bash script.

The name of the lambda function is coming in from a parameter. My goal was to simple change a variable so to restart the lambda function.

```
LAMBDA=$1

CURRENTVARIABLES=$(aws lambda get-function-configuration --function-name $LAMBDA | jq '.Environment.Variables')
NEWVARIABLES=$(echo $CURRENTVARIABLES | jq '. += {"kick":"'$(getrandom 8)'"}')
COMMAND="aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name $LAMBDA --environment '{\"Variables\":$NEWVARIABLES}'"
eval $COMMAND
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the Lambda Console you can just append new Environmental variables:

[image]

Doing it using the CLI is harder- [aws lambda update-function-configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-configuration.html) allows you to selectively update aspects of a lambda, but does not have helper methods to append enviornment variables. You can use [aws lambda get-function-configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/get-function-configuration.html) to get the *current* list of enviornment variables. Which could be used in tandem with some bash/powershell scripting (or language of your choice using the matching SDK functions).

For example:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const lambda = new AWS.lambda();

const FunctionName = 'FUNCTION_NAME';
const AppendVars = { key: value };

async function appendVars() {
  const { Environment: { Variables } } = await lambda.getFunctionConfiguration({ FunctionName }).promise();
  await lambda.updateFunctionConfiguration({
    FunctionName,
    Environment: { Variables: { ...Variables, ...AppendVars } },
  }).promise();
}

appendVars();
```

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping someone might be skilled enough at bash to chime in. "Oh just pipe this output into this command and you're good," or something like that. Wishful thinking : )

Comment: Alas that person isn't me! If you want to try your hand at JSON manipulation using bash you should check out 'jq' which is like sed but made for JSON. As an observation, we just redeploy every time an environment variable set changes; that way you get a full commit history.